# VBA Highlight multiple keywords with wildcard from text strings

Tags: vba, string, text, highlight

Any help here would be appreciated please.
The included VBA code almost meets the intended purpose, however, I need a solution that enables the use of wildcards and highlights all parameters contained between "##", "%%" or potentially other special characters (special characters included).
For instance, lets say in the cell range B2:B10 we would find something like:

> Checked at ##date1## and ##hour1##

But I want to be able to do a search and highlight using # * # or % * % within a selected determined cell range with the end result (bold being color):

> Checked at **##date1##** and **##hour1##**

```vb
Sub HighlightStrings()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cFnd As String
    Dim xTmp As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim xFNum As Integer
    Dim xArrFnd As Variant
    Dim xStr As String
    cFnd = InputBox("Please enter the text, separate them by comma:")
    If Len(cFnd) < 1 Then Exit Sub
    xArrFnd = Split(cFnd, ",")
    For Each Rng In Selection
    With Rng
    For xFNum = 0 To UBound(xArrFnd)
    xStr = xArrFnd(xFNum)
    y = Len(xStr)
    m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, xStr))
    If m > 0 Then
    xTmp = ""
    For x = 0 To m - 1
    xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, xStr)(x)
    .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    xTmp = xTmp & xStr
    Next
    End If
    Next xFNum
    End With
    Next Rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: I recommend you use indenting to make the code example easier to review.

Answer (score 0):

Okay This seems to work for me. There is a limitation we can work on if required: the phrase to highlight must be padded with spaces on both sides.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Sub testreplace()

Dim I As Integer        'Iteration
Dim FlagNum As Integer  'Flag Number
Dim RG As Range         'Whole range
Dim CL As Range         'Each Cell
Dim FlagChar As String  'Flag characters
Dim ArrFlag             'Flag Char Array
Dim TextTemp As String  'Cell Contents

Set RG = Selection
FlagChar = "##"
FlagChar = InputBox("Enter 'Flag Characters' separated by a comma." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Example:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "##,%%,&&" & vbCrLf & _
                "$$,XX", "Flag Characters to Highlight", "##,%%")

ArrFlag = Split(FlagChar, ",")

For Each CL In RG.Cells
    TextTemp = CL.Value
    For FlagNum = 0 To UBound(ArrFlag)
        For I = 1 To Len(TextTemp)
            'Debug.Print "<<" & Mid(TextTemp, I, Len(ArrFlag(Flagnum)) + 1) & _
                "=" & " " & ArrFlag(Flagnum) & ">>"
            If Mid(TextTemp, I, Len(ArrFlag(FlagNum)) + 1) = " " & ArrFlag(FlagNum) Then
                CL.Characters(I + 1, InStr(I, TextTemp, ArrFlag(FlagNum) & " ") + _
                    Len(ArrFlag(FlagNum)) - I).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next I
    Next FlagNum
Next CL
```

End Sub

Here's an example of it working:

[image: Reformatting Example]